# What is the Angular2 equivalent of $parse?

Tags: javascript, parsing, angular

My company has a widget that relies on the Angular 1.x $parse service.
Unfortunately, I could not find anything in Angular 2 that had the same functionality.

I found one article that said Angular2 wasn't going to implement it. Through more searching I did find this article: 
http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/pawel/2016/04/angular-2-interpolation-service.html 
which was helpful in finding the Angular 2 Parser.

Since we really need this functionality I set out to write something that would fulfill our needs. I am not done yet but my in progress code is here in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/YOaduK7ZjLoNhJE56Ugy?p=preview

$parse works like this:

```
var getFirstName = $parse('name.first');

//returns 'brian'
getFirstName({
    name: {
        first: 'brian'
    }
});

//returns 'james'
getFirstName({
    name: {
        first: 'james'
    }
});
```

Similarly, the ParseResolverFactory I wrote works like this:

```
var getFirstName = parseResolverFactory.getParseResolver('name.first');

//returns 'brian'
getFirstName.resolve({
    name: {
        first: 'brian'
    }
});

//returns 'james'
getFirstName.resolve({
    name: {
        first: 'james'
    }
});
```

If anyone has been successful in finding an equivalent of $parse, please let me know.

Comment: [this it?](https://github.com/peerigon/angular-expressions)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean a `get` function of TypeScript?

Say:

```
export class Element {
  private _class = { id: 0, name : 'Name' };

  get name() {
    return this._class.name;
  }
}
```